# Replace a marker in a text file with arbitrary new text

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a file which contains some text and - on a single line - a marker which indicates where new content should be added

```
foo
bar
%SUBSTITUTE%
foo
```

The line line substitute should be replaced by a new multiline string `text="some text"` (note that I do not know the string it may for instance be the result of reading a file `text=`cat "file"``). The result of the replacement should read

```
foo
bar
some text
%SUBSTITUTE%
foo
```

I had a working version based on `perl` which stopped working (apparently due to perl version change). Now I am trying standard utilities like `tr` and `sed` to replace the line. 
I am having some trouble with it, because the string to be pasted may contain arbitrary characters including backslashes etc. I do not want to escape these before pasting.

Is there a safe way to do it which works with standard tools? The other questions I find for the problem are particular solutions where the text to be pasted is known.

Comment: You might be able to use the venerable (and somewhat scary) m4. The use case you describe is very similar to its intended functionality.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I'm unclear on your example. Shouldn't your marker `%SUBSTITUTE%` be gone in the second piece of text? It's still there. You also have `The line line substitute`. iIs that intentional?

Comment: It should stay (which complicates the problem). The percent signs are to make it a `tex` comment. It indicates where the next chunk of text shall be inserted.

Comment: use this command: `sed '/%SUBSTITUTE%/i\some text\nnew line' file`

Comment: `some text` is an unknown text stored in a shell variable.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the GNU version of sed, you should be able to use the `r` command to read and insert new content from a file, then delete the marker line e.g.

```
sed '/%SUBSTITUTE%/{
r path/to/newcontent
d
}' file
```

If you want to retain the `%SUBSTITUTE%` marker *after* the insertion, that's tricky because whatever you do, the GNU `r` extension queues the file contents until the *end* of the current pattern cycle (retaining it *before* would just be a matter of removing the `d` command). Probably the simplest way is to append it to the `newcontent` file: you could do that on the fly like

```
sed '/%SUBSTITUTE%/{
r /dev/stdin
d
}' file < <(sed '$a %SUBSTITUTE%' path/to/newcontent)
```

---

Taking a completely different approach, you could split the first file on `%SUBSTITUTE%` and then cat in the new content

```
csplit -s file '/%SUBSTITUTE%/'
cat xx00 newcontent xx01
```

You could also do a bash `read` loop over the lines of the first file, and cat the new content file when you match the marker string - however I've had my knuckles rapped for suggesting read loops for text processing on this forum. Unfortunately neither provides an in-place solution.

Comment: It would better be GNU independent but I will try it. I would however need to re-insert the `%SUBSTITUTE%` because it should stay in the file to indicate where the next substitution is to be made.

Comment: `sed -e "/%SUBSTITUTE%/i$(sed 's/$/\\/' path/to/newcontent)" -e 's/\\$//' file` works too. The main trick is to blackslash newlines in `newcontent` than get it off. Note: If you have `\n`, `\t`, etc. its will substituted by its real meaning: «newline», «tab», etc.

Comment: Additionally in my `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` I found undocumented command `e`, so if supported you can do `sed -e '/%SUBSTITUTE%/e cat /path/to/newcontent' file`

Comment: You don't need GNU `sed` for `r` - but neither thr GNU nor any other version will insert *arbitrary text* as a replacement to *marker* - `r`only works on the end of the line cycle. @Costas suggestion, however, *would* work. But Costas - it is documented. Do `info sed`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way using `ed`.
Insert the whole content of `FILE` before the marker (i.e. before the line containing `%SUBSTITUTE%`):

```
ed -s originalfile <<< $'/%SUBSTITUTE%/- r FILE\nw\nq'
```

where:
`/%SUBSTITUTE%/` :  sets address at first line matching `%SUBSTITUTE%`
`-` or `-1` :  offsets address one line before
`r FILE` : `Reads FILE to after the addressed line.`
`w` : writes to `originalfile` (replace with `,p` to just print the content instead of writing)
`q` : quits editor

Replacing `FILE` with `!echo "$TEXT"` will insert the content of `$TEXT` before the marker:

```
export TEXT
ed -s originalfile <<'IN'
/%SUBSTITUTE%/-1 r !echo "$TEXT"
w
q
IN
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution based on `awk`:

```
text=`cat "filepaste"`
export text;
<"$file" awk '
    BEGIN {REPLACE=ENVIRON["text"] "\n%SUBSTITUTE%" }
    {gsub(/^%SUBSTITUTE%$/, REPLACE); print}
'
```

Here "filepaste" contains the content to substitute for `%SUBSTITUTE%`. An advantage is that this string may be acted upon using different shell tools without the need to save it back to a file.
Reading the `awk` variable `REPLACE` from the environment variable avoids the expansion of escaped characters in `text`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had a Perl solution, here's another. I am using `rep.txt` to store the replacement:

```
$ perl -pe '$re=`cat rep.txt`; chomp($re); s/%SUBSTITUTE%\n/$re/' file.txt
foo
bar
multi
  line
string
foo
```

That reads each line of the target file (`file.txt`), then applies the script given by `-e` to it and prints (`-p`).